# If row contains a specific value then serial number will be "-" or zero and red colored in RDLC report, and Group CountRows total skip the row

Tags: expression, rdlc, row-number, cumulative-sum, ssrs-expression

I need only those serial number who aren't discontinued employees. Sub total and Grand total count of employees exclude those employees. But their salary amount will be calculated in sub total and grand total.
The discontinued employees row will be red and serial number will be "-". But the following serial number will be consecutive number of previous serial no.

Expected Result:

Dept     ----- SL ---- Id -------------- Name   -- Discontinued -- Amount

```
        1   BP0003            A      No            5000
        2   BP0007            B      No            1000
        3   BP0016            C      No            2000
```

SubTotal--3 ---------------------------------------------------------- 8000

```
        -   BP0019            D     Yes            1000
        4   BP0033            E      No            2000
        5   BP0088            F      No            1500
        -   BP0094            G     Yes            1200
        6   BP0116            H      No            1300
        7   BP0119            I      No            2000
```

SubTotal--4 ---------------------------------------------------------- 9000

G.Total ---7 ----------------------------------------------------------17000

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Finally solved the issue..

SL No. Cell Expression

=IIF(
(Previous(RunningValue((IIf(Fields!is_discontinued.Value="Yes", 0,  CountRows("empId"))),Sum,"Tablix1"))
= RunningValue((IIf(Fields!is_discontinued.Value="Yes", 0,  CountRows("empId"))),Sum,"Tablix1")),
"-",
RunningValue(
(IIf(Fields!is_discontinued.Value = "Yes", 0,  CountRows("empId"))),Sum,"Tablix1") )

And

Sub Total and Grand Total Expression

=count(iif(Fields!is_discontinued.Value = "No", 1, nothing))

For Row Background Color Property Expression

= IIF(Fields!is_discontinued.Value = "Yes", "Tomato", "White")